# How to change this function from creating a circular gradient to an elliptical gradient?

Tags: python, math, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to create a function that doesn't rely on a perfect circle for a transparency gradient, but rather an elliptical that can be a perfect circle or can be an ellipse. Currently my function creates a square that contains a 1/4th of a circular gradient that is later mirrored in 3 directions to make a circle.

My function is defined as:

```
def _calc_mask(rx, ry): #rx and ry represent the pixels
    dx = rx - (width/2)   # horizontal center of Grating
    dy = ry - (width/2)  # vertical center of Grating

    t = math.atan2(dy, dx)
    r = math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
    ux = r * math.cos(t)
    uy = r * math.sin(t)
    f = math.exp(-0.5 * (ux / (self.std_dev*3)) ** 2 - 0.5 *
                 (uy / (self.std_dev*3)) ** 2)
    f = 1.0-f
    return 0, 0, 0, f
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your function because of the variable naming. However:

[image: Ellipse]

The `a^2` and `b^2` parts are what causes the squashing in one direction or the other.

To be able to have an ellipse that is not straight up and down you will have to use polar coordinates.

Comment: "To be able to have an ellipse that is not straight up and down you will have to use polar coordinates." This is not trure, see [here](http://www.maa.org/external_archive/joma/Volume8/Kalman/General.html)

Comment: Well evan058, your a beast! I should have said easier for most people. Since the various algebra syntax systems support substitution you could probably make a ellipse in differential equations, trig, linear algebra, arithmetic or heck even make one with quantum physics....No... with particles in a collider. You are correct Sir:)

Answer (score 0):

To obtain axis-aligned elliptical gradient, just use scale coefficients for dx and dy. For example: `dx = 2.0 * dx`

P.S. Your code

```
 t = math.atan2(dy, dx)
 r = math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
 ux = r * math.cos(t)
 uy = r * math.sin(t)
```

is completely useless - it gives `ux=dx, uy=dy`